# how to create a phpmailer with some particular conditions

Tags: php, arrays, phpmailer

i require help and suggestions to understand what i need to solve my actual php problem :/.

I need to create a phpmailer to send email to some users that i have stored in a db. My mysql db has two row: Object and Email address,  object is primary key and can be more email address for different objects. 
For example:

```
Maths    test@abc.it
Geo      abc@xyz.com
Story    test@abc.it
Philo    test@abc.it
Eng      quod@dfg.it
```

I need to send singular mail to every email address reporting all objects who they referes, but grouping objects for email address that has more once.

I have alreay created phpmailer to extract all datas with a sql query from db, and i know how send email correctly, but i don't know how i can group all objects for singolar Email Address and use it to send singular email without multiple of them.

Actually i can send automatically three different emails to test@abc.it where i report respectively: Math, Story and Philo, but i need to send only one email including three objects ( Math, Story and Philo ) in a singular email.

Can you give me some helps please, i'm in confusion?

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer on GitHub.

Comment: Hi Synchro, i know how to create phpmailer and i haven't problem for it. I have problem with php because i don't know as manage datas for my purpose. Ty

Comment: So do what I suggested?

Comment: There's nothing in phpmailer doc that help me for this purpose or i haven't find what do you refer.

Comment: @Zarbat Please include, in your question, the best attempt you have so far.  This question is currently too broad and requires too many assumptions to answer.  SO is not a free code writing service, we can help you if you isolate a single problem and express it in a simple, clear, and concise question.  Please edit your question and we may be able to help.